# What does it mean for a finite product topology to be a T1 space?

Tags: general-topology

If we define T1 space to be where all singletons are closed, then for a finite product topology, does T1 mean that all possible product of singletons are closed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $X=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a finite product of $T_1$ spaces, then $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}= \{x_1\} \times \ldots \{x_n\}$ is closed as a product of closed singletons in the factor spaces.

So yes, a (finite, in fact arbitrary) product of $T_1$ spaces is again $T_1$.

And if $X$ is $T_1$, then so is every $X_i$, $i=1, \ldots, n$ as these are open continuous images of $X$.